# Why storing return value avoids borrowing twice

Tags: rust

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::io::BufReader;
fn main() {
    let f = File::open("test.txt").expect("Can't open");
    let mut b = BufReader::new(f);
    let v = b.fill_buf().unwrap();
    println!("v: {:?}", v);

    b.consume(v.len());
}
```

will not compile, the error is

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `b` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:10:5
   |
7  |     let v = b.fill_buf().unwrap();
   |             ------------ first mutable borrow occurs here
...
10 |     b.consume(v.len());
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^-------^
   |     |         |
   |     |         first borrow later used here
   |     second mutable borrow occurs here
```

Changing the last lines to:

```
let len = v.len();
b.consume(len);
```

And all is ok.

I fail to understand why the first example is borrowing something twice, and why storing the length in a variable and passing that variable to `b.consume()` is ok - could someone explain why the 2. variant is ok, and the first is not ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run into this kind of issue, it can help to desugar things a bit. As you may know, method syntax is syntax sugar for an associated function call:

```rust
b.consume(v.len());
// desugars to
BufRead::consume(&mut b, [_]::len(v));
```

Argument expressions are generally evaluated left-to-right, so we try to get a new mutable reference to `b` before we release the reference we're holding in `v`. There are some cases where the compiler can recognize and automatically avoid this issue, but this does not seem to be one of those cases.

You may ask "Why does it say second mutable reference? `v` is an immutable reference!" Well, the lifetime of the reference in `v` is tied to the lifetime of the mutable reference when you call `b.fill_buf()`. So the compiler thinks that the mutable reference to `b` must remain valid until `v` is released.

The reason the fix works is because it flips the order of the arguments, evaluating `v.len()` first, and releasing that first reference.